# Can you attach a terminal to IJulia Notebook in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia, jupyter

Usually, when working in VSCode, I can attach a file to REPL (`Ctrl + Shift + P > Attach to session`) and then any code I write can be executed by running the file by going `Ctrl + Shift + P > Julia: Execute ...`

This way, I can view the variables just by typing them out in the REPL among other things.

However when I try code in a Juptyter notebook, this doesnt seem to work. Is there any way of starting a terminal that shares the variables inside the notebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, notebook kernels use different logic than the REPL process. You can access the workspace, but code execution is only possible in the notebook itself. There are no plans to change this behaviour currently.